# Getting error on the beforeAction method when running Yii::app()->getModule('admin')->user

Tags: yii

I am getting this error when running 
`Yii::app()->getModule('admin')->user` this method on the beforeAction method:
`Property "AdminModule.user" is not defined.`

The controller component resides on the `modules/admin/components folder`

Comment: The error is clear. There is no property `user` in the `AdminModule` class. What are you trying to get with `Yii::app()->getModule('admin')->user`?

Comment: The user object property exist on the WebAdmin Component, is there a way that the WebAdmin component can be access on the beforeAction method of Controller component?